# Activating autoSubscribeNewMembers on a group created by graph api

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to activate autoSubscribeNewMembers on a group that i create with a call to graph api.

I was trying to add a line for "autoSubscribeNewMembers = true" while creating the group but it doesnt work and i'm getting a message the indicate that this option is not supported at the moment.

The only workaround i found was by doing a second request with a "PATCH" request with the ID of the newly created group :

```
        var autoSubscribeFix = new
        {
            autoSubscribeNewMembers = true
        };
        using (var response = await _httpClient.PatchAsJsonAsync($"{GraphAPIEndpoint}/myorganization/groups/{id}", autoSubscribeFix))
```

To do so, i expose myself to a lot of "Bad request" until the group is exposed enough to recieve the PATCH request with success.

This parameter is "false by default" and cannot be specified while creating a group... wich is very strange :/ In Office 365 the option is checked by default so one could hope the same for the api.

Am i wrong to think there should be a better way than a PATCH request after the creation ? Is there a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no better way to set that property for a newly created group than via a separate PATCH request right now. We'll add support for setting all group properties in a single request in the future. Currently autoSubscribeNewMembers and allowExternalSenders can't be set together with the other group properties. The limitation is only applicable to write requests.

Comment: I can create groups, add / remove members / owners, but when I try to set autoSubscribeNewMembers, I'm getting an error with this message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.

Comment: Are you trying to set it for an Office 365/Unified group? If so please provide a sample request-id returned by a failing call.

Comment: Has this issue been resolved yet? I am still having this same problem with no explanation from Microsoft on when this issue will be resolved. Why?